# Scraping wiki (Not wikipedia) infobox

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, wiki

I am able to scrape the infobox on any Wikipedia site using `rvest` but I want to do the same on a wiki page but can't get it working ...

The link: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(Diana_Prince)
On the page you have the infobox (which looks like a normal Wikipedia table) the CSS selector appears to be ".pi-layout-default"

I want a data frame that contains the real name, aliases etc..

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: `a wiki page` doesn't describe any kind of HTML content or structure. They are just HTML pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rvest` and `selectorgadet`!

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

read_html("https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(Diana_Prince)") %>%
  html_nodes(".pi-font , .pi-data-label") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) %>%
  as_tibble()
# A tibble: 21 x 2
   V1                V2                                                                                                               
   <chr>             <chr>                                                                                                            
 1 Real Name         Diana of Themyscira                                                                                              
 2 Current Alias     Wonder Woman                                                                                                     
 3 Aliases           Diana Prince, Princess Diana, Miss America, Goddess of Truth, Dinanna Truthqueen                                 
 4 Relatives         Ares (grandfather)[1]Hippolyta (mother)Antiope (aunt, deceased)Theseus (uncle by Antiope, deceased)Hippolytus (c~
 5 Affiliation       Justice League · formerly Department of Metahuman Affairs, Star Sapphire Corps, Female Furies, White Lantern Cor~
 6 Base Of Operatio~ Washington, D.C. · Themyscira · JLA Watchtower, Hall of Justice · formerly Boston, Gateway City                  
 7 Alignment         Good                                                                                                             
 8 Identity          Public Identity                                                                                                  
 9 Race              Amazon                                                                                                           
10 Citizenship       Amazon                                                                                                           
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!! Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: One short question, I tried using the selectorgadget too but how did you find the .pi-data-label Selector? I can't seem to locate it ..

Comment: It was a bit of trial and error. I had to select the rows in the box, but deselected the title rows.